# How to make a class function similarly to a nested dictionary?

Tags: python

## What I'm trying to do

I'm trying to make a class that can store and manipulate multiple sets of data.

However, I'm having trouble making accessing the data as easy and intuitive as possible. The object is intended to essentially just be a nested dictionary, with the layout looking something like:

```py
data = { "File1_Column1": {'header': [...],
                           'data':   [...]},
         "File1_Column2": {'header': [...],
                           'data':   [...]}, ...}
```

## What I want to happen

Assuming I have an instance of this class named `data`, I want `data['File1_Column1']['header']` and `data['File1_Column1']['data']` to return what one would expect, but I'd also like `data['File1_Column1']` to return the same thing as `data['File1_Column1']['data']`. I want this because I can foresee myself using the data list 99% of the time, and this would make it more convenient.

The former two are pretty straightforward to do by simply utilizing `__getitem__`, *however*, I'm really struggling to get the latter to work.

The closest I've gotten is shown in my simplified code below. I've tried implementing an if-statement to the `Data` class's `__getitem__` method in various ways, checking whether or not the `Subscript` class's `__getitem__` method was called, but have had no luck.

## What I've tried already

```py
class Data:

    def __init__(self):
        self._data = {}

    def append(self, label, data):
        self._data[label] = data

    def __getitem__(self, label):

        class Subscript:

            def __init__(self, data):
                self._data = data

            def __getitem__(self, label):
                return self._data[label]

        subdata = Subscript(self._data[label])
        return subdata

data = Data()
example = {'header': ['Trace', 'Unit'], 'data': [1, 2, 3, 4]}
data.append('Label', example)
print(data['Label'])
print(data['Label']['data'])
print(data['Label']['header'])
```

## The results

```
<__main__.Data.__getitem__.<locals>.Subscript object at 0x007B4B10>
[1, 2, 3, 4]
['Trace', 'Unit']
```

## What I expect to happen

```
[1, 2, 3, 4]
[1, 2, 3, 4]
['Trace', 'Unit']
```

Is there a way to do this?

Comment: how do you want to distinguish calling a column in the object ( `data['File1_Column1']` ) and calling the data in the column ( `data['File1_Column1']` ) ?

Comment: Don't think it's possible. You're expecting `data['Label']` to evaluate to either the `Subscript` or `[1,2,3,4]` based on what comes after the `data['Label']`. Since python can't see the future, this ain't possible

Comment: I had figured that was the case, but I was hoping there was something that I just wasn't seeing. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

maybe you just use 2 dicts for different items:

```
headers= { "File1_Column1": ...,
            "File1_Column2": ...
            },

data  = {"File1_Column1": ..., 
          "File1_Column2": ...}
```

Answer (score -1):

It's possible to do this with a **repr** method.

You can add a **repr** method to the Subscript class.

```
def __repr__(self):
    return str(self._data['data'])
```

Here is the code with the repr method and an added example -

```
class Data:

    def __init__(self):
        self._data = {}

    def append(self, label, data):
        self._data[label] = data

    def __getitem__(self, label):


        class Subscript:

            def __init__(self, data):
                self._data = data
                self.label = label

            def __getitem__(self, label):
                self.label = label
                return self._data[label]

            def __repr__(self):
                return str(self._data['data'])

        subdata = Subscript(self._data[label])
        return subdata

data = Data()
example = {'header': ['Trace', 'Unit'], 'data': [1, 2, 3, 4]}
example2 = {'header': ['Trace2', 'Unit2'], 'data': [11, 22, 33, 42]}
data.append('Label', example)
data.append('Label2', example2)
print(data['Label'])
print(data['Label']['data'])
print(data['Label']['header'])
print(data['Label2'])
print(data['Label2']['data'])
print(data['Label2']['header'])
```

### The Results (What you expect to happen) -

```
Shreyashs-MacBook-Pro:~ shreyash$ python test.py 
[1, 2, 3, 4]
[1, 2, 3, 4]
['Trace', 'Unit']
[11, 22, 33, 42]
[11, 22, 33, 42]
['Trace2', 'Unit2']
```

Comment: That only changes what the object looks like, not what it actually is. You're putting your object in a little list costume, but try to use it as if it were the list it looks like, and it'll completely fail.